# Herencia en c++ (paso de parametros de un objeto de tipo clase padre a una clase hija) error clase no definida

Tags: c++, poo, lista, herencia

Como puedo hacer para implementar una funcion que me permita agregar al final de una lista actual los elementos de otra lista enviada por parámetros.

Ejemplo:

```
#include "List.h"

class LinkedList<E> : public List<E> {};
```

***clase padre:*** List

***clase hija:*** LinkedList

```
void LinkedList::extend(List<E> L){}
```

mi problema es que no se como mandar el parametro (List L) me da error y me dice que la clase List no existe

Comment: Deberías proporcionar un [mcve] que permita entender tu problema. Con las 3 líneas de código que has puesto, es difícil precisar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurro con el usuario @Trauma (todavía no puedo agregar comentarios directos a tu pregunta :-)).  Las clases que estás describiendo son plantillas de clase, pero en tu descripción no utilizas ninguna declaración de las clases como plantillas de clase.

Deberás tener algo similar a:

```
// List.h

template<typename E>
class List {
  ...
};

// LinkedList.h
#include "List.h"

template<typename E>
class LinkedList : public List<E> {
  ...
};
```

Comment: Gracias ya lo pude resolver !!